# Given a point outside of an arc, how can one find the point on the arc which extends to that point?

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line

Given a point outside of an arc, how can one find the point on the arc which extends to that point?

For example, the radius of the circle (**R**) is 10cm, it's center point is [0,0].
The origin (**o**) of the line (**8**) is at  [-3, 10]
How can we find the point (**p**) (p8) were the tangent at that point continues to the origin of the line?

A brute force solution would not be acceptable.

[image: Extensions of arc]

Comment: What's a "brute force solution"?

Comment: You mean find the point of tangency of (one of the 2) tangent(s) issued from this point to the circle. ?

Comment: @LeeMosher brute force means looping through equations until one finds the closest match. In this case loop through the degrees from 0 to 90 and see if the tangent intersects the point.

Comment: @JeanMarie Correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly, you want to find the point at which the tangent of the circle that passes through [-3, 10] touches the circle. Using the fact that a radius to that point will be perpendicular to the tangent, we can find that point quite easily. Lets build the triangle with vertices in [-3, 10], [0, 0] and the point we are trying to find. It will be a right triangle, so we can use the Pythagoras theorem. We know the length of one of the catheti is 10 (radius), and the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{3^2 + 10^2} = \sqrt{109}$. The length of the second cathetus will therefore be $\sqrt{109 - 10^2} = 3$. Lets build a circle with this radius and the center in [-3, 10]. The point of intersection of two circles will be the desired point.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, now all that needs to be figured out is how to get the point of intersection of the 2 curves. I think that is well documented but if you added it here it would be a help.

Comment: how to get the point of intersection of 2 circles? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219802/a-javascript-function-that-returns-the-x-y-points-of-intersection-between-two-ci

Answer (score 1):

Construct a half-circle on diameter $PO$ (see figure below) to intersect the circle at tangency point $T$. That works because $\angle OTP=90°$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, If I could mark 2 answers as correct I would! I also asked the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60156373/given-a-point-outside-of-an-arc-how-can-one-find-the-point-on-the-arc-which-ext and a link was posted to https://sites.math.washington.edu/~m124/source/supps/circleTangents.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I came up with. I'm sure it can be improved but my math is not holding there!

Based on @Aretino answer.

1. Make a circle with a radius half the distance between `o` and `p`, originate it at the midpoint of the line `op`.
2. Calculate the intersection point of the original circle and the newly made circle.

Can see a working snippet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60156373/given-a-point-outside-of-an-arc-how-can-one-find-the-point-on-the-arc-which-ext/60171900#60171900

[image: Intersection point]

```
// Function to find tangent intersection points to a point outside of the circle
// Credits
// https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3541795/given-a-point-outside-of-an-arc-how-can-one-find-the-point-on-the-arc-which-ext/3541928#3541928
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60156373/given-a-point-outside-of-an-arc-how-can-one-find-the-point-on-the-arc-which-ext
/**
 *
 *
 * @param {number} centerX1 Center of circle 1 X
 * @param {number} centerY1 Center of circle 1 Y
 * @param {number} radius1 Radius of circle 1
 * @param {number} centerX2 Center of circle 2 X
 * @param {number} centerY2 Center of circle 2 Y
 * @param {number} radius2 Radius of circle 2
 * @returns {object | boolean} The to intersect points { point1: [x1, y1], point2: [x2, y2] } or false
 * @credit Math based on https://www.analyzemath.com/CircleEq/circle_intersection_calcu.html
 */
var circleIntersections = function(
  centerX1,
  centerY1,
  radius1,
  centerX2,
  centerY2,
  radius2
) {
  var a, b, c, A, B, C, delta, x1, x2, y1, y2;

  a = -(centerY1 - centerY2) / (centerX1 - centerX2);
  b = 2 * (centerX1 - centerX2);
  c =
    (-radius1 * radius1 +
      radius2 * radius2 +
      centerX1 * centerX1 -
      centerX2 * centerX2 +
      centerY1 * centerY1 -
      centerY2 * centerY2) /
    b;
  A = a * a + 1;
  B = 2 * a * c - 2 * centerX1 * a - 2 * centerY1;
  C =
    c * c +
    centerX1 * centerX1 -
    2 * centerX1 * c +
    centerY1 * centerY1 -
    radius1 * radius1;
  delta = B * B - 4 * A * C;
  if (delta < 0) {
    return false;
  }
  y1 = (-B + Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * A);
  x1 = a * y1 + c;
  y2 = (-B - Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * A);
  x2 = a * y2 + c;

  return {
    point1: [x1, y1],
    point2: [x2, y2]
  };
};

/**
 *
 *
 * @param {number} centerX Center of circle X
 * @param {number} centerY Center of circle Y
 * @param {number} radius Radius of circle
 * @param {number} pointX Point to tangent to X
 * @param {number} pointY Point to tangent to Y
 * @returns {object | boolean} The to intersect points { point1: [x1, y1], point2: [x2, y2] } or false
 */
var tangentLines = function(centerX, centerY, radius, pointX, pointY) {
  var centerX2, centerY2, radius2, dX, dY;
  centerX2 = centerX - (centerX - pointX) / 2;
  centerY2 = centerY - (centerY - pointY) / 2;
  dX = centerX2 - centerX;
  dY = centerY2 - centerY;
  radius2 = Math.sqrt(dX * dX + dY * dY);

  return circleIntersections(
    centerX,
    centerY,
    radius,
    centerX2,
    centerY2,
    radius2
  );
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
        <div>
          <div>
            centerX: <input v-model="centerX" @input="intersectionPoints">
            centerY:  <input v-model="centerY" @input="intersectionPoints">
            <div>radius: <input v-model="radius" @input="intersectionPoints"></div>
          </div>
          <div>
            pointX: <input v-model="pointX" @input="intersectionPoints">
            pointY: <input v-model="pointY" @input="intersectionPoints">
          </div>
          <div v-if=result>
          <div>point1: {{result.point1}}</div>
          <div>point2: {{result.point2}}</div>
          </div>
          <div v-if=!result>No intersections :-(</div>
        </div>
            `,
  data: function() {
    return {
      centerX: 200,
      centerY: 200,
      radius: 100,
      pointX: 160,
      pointY: 100,
      result: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    intersectionPoints() {
      this.result = tangentLines(
        this.centerX,
        this.centerY,
        this.radius,
        this.pointX,
        this.pointY
      );
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.intersectionPoints();
  }
});

// Without Vue just use something like
// tangentLines(200, 200, 100, 160, 100);
```

```
div {
margin:5px;
}
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id=app></div>
```